# Writing data to a thrift file

Tags: python, thrift

I want to write an app which create a thrift file in python.Any idea where can I get the proper documentation along with installation guide

Examples are welcome!

Comment: I don't really know Thrift, but isn't a "Thrift file" an interface definition?  And you would like to write *data* to a file containing an interface definition?  I don't quite get that.

Answer (score 0):

5 seconds googling 'thrift file python' yields [thrift 1.0](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/thrift/1.0).  Is this what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

There were no tutorial whatsover on the web... So I created one. You can check my full tutorial about Thrift in : [My Blog](http://www.alireza-noori.com/programming/thriftpart-one-introduction/) It's pretty thorough I think. If you had any more questions, just ask here or comment on my blog. I'll be more than happy to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

Download thrift from http://thrift.apache.org/download/
read tutorial/README and tutorial/tutorial.thrift
the python C/S code is in tutorial/py